# Linkedin ugc post was not published properly

Tags: linkedin-api

API Post creation responded with status 201 and with a post id `urn:li:ugcPost:6767685388107599872`. However, the post is not visible on the network and also it's not possible to retrieve the data of the post.

Retrieve endpoint

`GET /v2/ugcPosts/urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A6767685388107599872?viewContext=AUTHOR`

Response

```
{
    "message": "com.linkedin.restli.server.RestLiServiceException [HTTP Status:404]: com.linkedin.content.common.ResponseException: ",
    "status": 404
}
```

Retrieve endpoint

`GET /v2/ugcPosts/urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A6767685388107599872`

Response

```
{
    "message": "com.linkedin.restli.server.RestLiServiceException [HTTP Status:404]: com.linkedin.content.common.ResponseException: ",
    "status": 404
}
```

There was no issue on the Linkedin status page related to the publishing time `2021-02-17T06:05:34.052Z`.

I also tried to publish the exact same content on a different page without any problem.

Do you have any idea what could go wrong?

Comment: Any progress on this?